# Why is event binding in jQuery so much slower than native javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have put up a little [JSPerf](http://www.jsperf.com) to test out performance of event bindings in Javascript. I knew that native javascript will be the fastest, but what really suprised me, by how bug margin is jQuery slower. And also a big difference between running jQuery binding on javascript object and on jQuery object.

Code I have used is below. [JSPerf for this code is here](http://jsperf.com/rychlost-events).

```
var div = document.createElement('DIV');
var handler = function(){};
var jq_div = $('div');

// #1 - native javascript test code
div.addEventListener('click', handler);

// #2 - jquery event binding on javascript object
$(div).on('click', handler);

// #3 - jquery event binding on jquery object
jq_div.on('click', handler);
```

Can someone explain me why are these difference, mainly between cases #2 and #3. I wasn't expecting much difference there. And also, if there is any way how to improve jquery event binding perfomance ?

Thank you for your effort in advance.

Comment: Notice, that the jQuery example adds an event handler to every `div` found on a page, the native code adds only one (to the newly-created one).

Comment: Sorry, I have edited JSPerf example: http://jsperf.com/rychlost-events I am relatively new to JSPerf, I didn't realize this. Thanks, now I see other numbers, more what I had expected.

Comment: Item #2 is not only measuring the time to attach an event handler, but also to create a jQuery object from `div`. A fairer test for #2 would be `var $div = $(div);` outside of your testing loop, then insider the loop just `$div.on('click',handler);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can someone explain me why are these difference

jQuery has to do everything that the native binding does - plus a huge lot of overhead that jQuery uses for its internal event system.

> mainly between cases #2 and #3

Your `var jq_div = $('div');` is wrong. It does select *all `div` elements in the page* and will bind events to all of them; you wanted `var jq_div = $(div);` or `var jq_div = $('<div>');`.

> Is there any way how to improve jquery event binding perfomance?

No. And there's absolutely no need. *Binding* (in contrast to "firing") an event happens almost never in an application - it's a very rare task. And as your jsperf test confirms, it still is happening thousands of times per second, which is fast enough. If you really find yourself needing to bind events to very many elements at a time, use event delegation.